# OnActivityResult not working (Android)

Tags: android, android-intent

I am using a simple function OnActivityResult, but it is not returning me desired results.

Please see my code and tell me where i am doing wrong.

```
public void OnClickFunction(View view)
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Second.class);
    startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_OK);

///     My actions. . . 
}
```

Then in the Second class, i have set Result like this:

```
Button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ValueOne = EditText.getText().toString().trim();
            if (ValueOne.equals(String.valueOf(Answer)))
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Correct Answer", 0).show();
                Second.this.setResult(RESULT_OK, null);
                Second.this.finish();
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Wrong Answer", 0).show();
            }
        }
    });
```

Now coming back to the first.class, from where the Intent was called:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
//      if (requestCode == RESULT_OK)
//      {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
                             /////  MyActions. . . 
        }
//      }
}
```

The debugger is not debugging this function, so the desired results are not coming.
Where i am doing wrong??

Comment: Are you sure your activities are in the same task? Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4013586/onactivityresult-does-not-works-in-android

Comment: are you sure that the if condition is true and it's toast the correct answer message display? and you can also use setResult(RESULT_OK) instead of setResult(RESULT_OK,null);

Comment: Button.setOnClickListener ????

Comment: @Pratik.. yes the CORRECT ANSWER toast is shown.
i also have used setResult(RESULT_OK) only but same problem.

Comment: @Ash... yes both activites are of same task.

Comment: @WalidHossain... yes onClick on Button.

Comment: @Noman: y r u passing RESULT_OK in `startActivityForResult()` , u need to pass request_code there, (any int value of ur choice) and do a `if (requestCode== ur choice int) ` before checking `if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to destroy the second activity. Try pressing back button. I am able to see all the log messages in onActivityResult

First Activity

```
public class FirstActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
int result = 100;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i, result);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.i("H", "RequestCode:" + requestCode);
    Log.i("H", "ResultCode:" + resultCode );
}
}
```

SecondActivity

```
public class SecondActivity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    Log.i("S","Exiting Second Activity");
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in Source Class:

```
int activity=1;
Intent i=new Intent(Sourceclass.this,destination.class);
startActivityForResult(i,activity);
```

In Destination class:

```
Intent i=new Intent();
      setResult(RESULT_OK,i);
    finish();
```

In OnActivityResult of Source Class:

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
 {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) 
   {
                   if(requestCode==1)
            {
                Log.e("check","check");

            }
   }

}
```

Comment: @abhi.. yes i edited my code according to ur answer but problem is there still

Comment: your activity extend    " extends AppCompatActivity "

Answer (score -1):

in my case: when use activityForResult,  I add this flag :

addFlags(FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)

when delete this flag ,fixed